# R Shiny reactive table output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a reactive table but my output is not responding to my if statements. Here's a reproducible example. Changing Y1 results in a 0.1 increase, but that should be an entire table for Var1 values of 1-10. Also I'm not sure where "data" is coming from. This table should have 4 vectors: Var1, X1, Units, Y1 and 10 rows/observations.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- fluidPage(
fluidPage(title = "Repro"),
tags$head(
tags$style(
  HTML(".shiny-notification {
       position:fixed;
       top: calc(50% - 150px);
       left: calc(50% - 150px);
       }
       "
  )
  )
  ),
useShinyjs(),
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("winprint")),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  textInput("name", "Name"),
  numericInput("Y1", "Y1", value = 0, min =0, max = 200),
  actionButton("print", "PRINT")
  
),
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Random Var1",tableOutput("x1"))
     )
   )
 )
     )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  X1 <- c(0.01, 0.1, 0.04, 5, 2, 0.04, 0.01, 100, 4, 0.5)
  Units <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c")
  table <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1,X1,Units))


  Y1 <- reactive({
get(input$Y1, inherits = FALSE)
  })



 output$x1 <- renderTable({

Var1 = table$Var1
X1 = table$X1
Units = table$Units
X2 = if (table$Var1 == 1){
  input$Y1*0.01
} else if (table$Var1 == 2){
  input$Y1*1
} else if (table$Var1 == 3){
  input$Y1*0.04
} else if (table$Var1 == 4){
  input$Y1*50
} else if (table$Var1 ==5){
  input$Y1*2
} else if (table$Var1 == 6){
  input$Y1*0.04
} else if (table$Var1 == 7){
  input$Y1*0.01
} else if (table$Var1 == 8){
  (input$Y1*100)/1000
} else if (table$Var1 == 9){
  input$Y1*4
} else if (table$Var1 == 10){
  input$Y1*0.5
}



 })




observeEvent(input$print, {
   js$winprint()

  })
}



# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if`/`else` use `ifelse` or `case_when` from `dplyr` which can be directly used on vectors.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(title = "Repro"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(".shiny-notification {
       position:fixed;
       top: calc(50% - 150px);
       left: calc(50% - 150px);
       }
       "
      )
    )
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("winprint")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Name"),
      numericInput("Y1", "Y1", value = 0, min =0, max = 200),
      actionButton("print", "PRINT")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Random Var1",tableOutput("x1"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  X1 <- c(0.01, 0.1, 0.04, 5, 2, 0.04, 0.01, 100, 4, 0.5)
  Units <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c")
  table <- data.frame(Var1,X1,Units)
  
  
  Y1 <- reactive({
    get(input$Y1, inherits = FALSE)
  })
  
  
  
  output$x1 <- renderTable({
    transform(table, X2 = input$Y1 * case_when(Var1 %in% c(1, 7, 8) ~ 0.01, 
                                    Var1 == 2 ~ 1, 
                                    Var1 %in% c(3, 6) ~ 0.04, 
                                    Var1 == 4 ~ 50, 
                                    Var1 == 5 ~ 2, 
                                    Var1 == 9 ~ 4, 
                                    Var1 == 10 ~ 0.5))
    
    
  })

  observeEvent(input$print, {
    js$winprint()
  })
}

# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]